# Get star employee record from attendance according to each Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Employee and Employee details table. In Employee table it has column like `Id(Primary Key), Name, Gender, Joining Date, Department` and so on.

In Employee Details Table it has column like `Id(Primary Key), Employee Table Id(Foreign Key), Current Salary, Daily login Time, Daily logout time` and so on.

What I am trying to achieve is, finding the STAR Employee of the month. The formula is,

- First I need to find the attendance of each employee according to the month,
  which I am able to do and below is the result.

| Id | Name | Attendance | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ryan | 20 | January |
| 2 | Joanna | 19 | January |
| 3 | Tom | 21 | January |
| 4 | Lucy | 10 | January |
| 5 | Frank | 15 | January |
| 6 | Jane | 17 | January |
| 7 | Robert | 11 | January |
| 8 | Ryan | 18 | February |
| 9 | Joanna | 17 | February |
| 10 | Tom | 20 | February |
| 11 | Lucy | 16 | February |
| 12 | Frank | 15 | February |
| 13 | Jane | 17 | February |
| 14 | Robert | 11 | February |
| 15 | Ryan | 22 | March |
| 16 | Joanna | 19 | March |
| 17 | Tom | 11 | March |
| 18 | Lucy | 10 | March |
| 19 | Frank | 15 | March |
| 20 | Jane | 17 | March |
| 21 | Robert | 15 | March |

- Then I need to find the Highest Attendance of the month and 15% less will be the lowest attendance, If any employee fall in this range then that employee will will be the STAR employee of the month.

In this second step I am facing all the problem. I am able to get Highest and Lowest attendance but not able to compare.

Here is my query for calculating this:

```
SELECT MAX(Attendance) AS [Highest Attendance], 
MAX(Attendance) - ( MAX(Attendance) * .15 ) AS [Lowest Attendance], Month
FROM Employee 
GROUP BY Month;
```

Can anyone please help me with this?
I am using SQL Server 2017.

Here is some dummy data to create the above scenario:

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE Employee (
  Id int PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  Attendance int NOT NULL,
  Month varchar(20) NOT NULL
);
-- insert some values
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (1, 'Ryan', 20, 'January');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (2, 'Joanna', 19, 'January');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (3, 'Tom', 21, 'January');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (4, 'Lucy', 10, 'January');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (5, 'Frank', 15, 'January');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (6, 'Jane', 17, 'January');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (7, 'Robert', 11, 'January');

INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (8, 'Ryan', 18, 'February');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (9, 'Joanna', 17, 'February');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (10, 'Tom', 20, 'February');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (11, 'Lucy', 16, 'February');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (12, 'Frank', 15, 'February');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (13, 'Jane', 17, 'February');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (14, 'Robert', 11, 'February');

INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (15, 'Ryan', 22, 'March');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (16, 'Joanna', 19, 'March');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (17, 'Tom', 11, 'March');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (18, 'Lucy', 10, 'March');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (19, 'Frank', 15, 'March');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (20, 'Jane', 17, 'March');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (21, 'Robert', 15, 'March');
```

My Expected example output is like:

| Name | Month | Employee Attendance | Highest Attendance | Lowest Attendance | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ryan | January | 20 | 21 | 17.85 | STAR EMPLOYEE |

Comment: *I am using SQL Server 18* - FYI you're not. Your choices are 2012/2014/2016/2017/2019.

Comment: @Stu Sorry, My mistake, updated it.

Comment: Why is Ryan January's star employee and not Tom, who has 21 vs 20?

Comment: No no no, they all can be, theta's just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the above scenario in many ways but I would like to use [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Common table expressions (CTEs) allow you to structure and organize your SQL queries.

```
WITH calculated_value AS(
    SELECT MAX(Attendance) AS [Highest Attendance], 
    (MAX(Attendance) - ( MAX(Attendance) * .15 )) AS [Lowest Attendance], Month
    FROM Employee 
    group by Month
)
SELECT e.Name, e.Month, e.Attendance as [Employee Attendance], cv.[Highest Attendance],
       cv.[Lowest Attendance], 
       'STAR EMPLOYEE' AS [Status]
FROM calculated_value AS cv
JOIN Employee AS e ON e.Month = cv.Month
WHERE e.Attendance <= cv.[Highest Attendance] AND e.Attendance >= cv.[Lowest Attendance]
```

**N.B:** Joining with months I won't prefer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *totally* sure what you are after, but if you want to apply a status based on the attendance being greater than a minimum you can do something along the following lines using *window functions*

```
with m as (
    select *, Max(attendance) over(partition by [month]) HighestAttendance
    from employee
)
select [Name], [Month], Attendance, 
    HighestAttendance, LowestAttendance,
    case when Attendance > LowestAttendance then 'Star employee' else 'you suck' end Status
from m
cross apply(values(HighestAttendance-(HighestAttendance*0.15)))v(LowestAttendance)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most calculations can be done in a sub-query.

> ```
> SELECT 
>   [Name]
> , [Month]
> , Attendance          AS [Employee Attendance]
> , AttendanceMax       AS [Highest Attendance]
> , AttendanceThreshold AS [Lowest Attendance] 
> , CASE 
>   WHEN Attendance >= AttendanceThreshold 
>   THEN 'STAR EMPLOYEE' 
>   END AS Status
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT *
>   , [MonthNumber] = CHARINDEX(UPPER(LEFT([Month], 3)),'___JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC') 
>   , [AttendanceMax] = MAX(attendance) OVER (PARTITION BY [month])
>   , [AttendanceThreshold] = ROUND((1-0.15)*MAX(attendance) OVER (PARTITION BY [month]), 2)
>   FROM employee
> ) q
> WHERE Attendance >= AttendanceThreshold
> ORDER BY [MonthNumber] ASC, Attendance DESC
> ```

> ```
> Name   | Month    | Employee Attendance | Highest Attendance | Lowest Attendance | Status       
> :----- | :------- | ------------------: | -----------------: | ----------------: | :------------
> Tom    | January  |                  21 |                 21 |             17.85 | STAR EMPLOYEE
> Ryan   | January  |                  20 |                 21 |             17.85 | STAR EMPLOYEE
> Joanna | January  |                  19 |                 21 |             17.85 | STAR EMPLOYEE
> Tom    | February |                  20 |                 20 |             17.00 | STAR EMPLOYEE
> Ryan   | February |                  18 |                 20 |             17.00 | STAR EMPLOYEE
> Joanna | February |                  17 |                 20 |             17.00 | STAR EMPLOYEE
> Jane   | February |                  17 |                 20 |             17.00 | STAR EMPLOYEE
> Ryan   | March    |                  22 |                 22 |             18.70 | STAR EMPLOYEE
> Joanna | March    |                  19 |                 22 |             18.70 | STAR EMPLOYEE
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b184695c0ed23ee78daa2e0749ccc8f)*